# Error: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found object

Tags: python, pytorch, data-science, torch, pytorch-dataloader

I'm creating a dataloader with a dataset.

```
train_dl = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=8, shuffle=True)
```

The dataset contains 2 elements per index: a matrix and an array.

```
a, b = train_ds.__getitem__(0)
print(type(a))
print(a)
print(type(b))
print(b)
```

returns:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

[[ 44.9329    46.08967   44.9329   ...  99.2188    99.735664  99.17029 ]
 [ 44.9329    44.9329    44.9329   ... 114.164474 114.292244 114.11395 ]
 [ 44.9329    45.03071   44.9329   ... 114.57378  114.56599  114.49552 ]
 ...
 [ 44.9329    44.9329    44.9329   ...  52.242996  50.12293   44.9329  ]
 [ 44.9329    44.9329    44.9329   ...  44.9329    44.9329    44.9329  ]
 [ 44.9329    44.9329    44.9329   ...  44.9329    44.9329    44.9329  ]]

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

[-0.002963486 -0.003033393 0.00371422 2.02e-06 0.004402838 -0.002704915
 0.003289625 -0.002551801 -0.003632823 -0.003408553 -0.002707387
 0.00278949 0.000828761 0.000849513 0.003992096 -0.002692624 0.001183484
 9.43e-05 0.003836168 2.24e-05 0.003944455 -0.001950883 -0.000877485
 0.001734729 -0.003225849 -0.000537016 6.53e-05 -0.003643878 -0.002444321
 0.002499692 0.001538219 0.002263657 0.003073046 0.004134932 -0.002500862
 -0.001662471 0.002273667 0.00375025 0.001866289 -0.002027481 0.002197658
 -0.002243473 0.000943156 -0.000643054 -0.003169563 -0.003424202
 0.00118924 -0.003570424 0.002273526]
```

But when trying to iterate my dataloader with:

```
for i, data in enumerate(train_dl):
```

I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 num_epochs=1   # Just for demo, adjust this higher.
----> 2 training(myModel, train_dl, num_epochs)

 in training(model, train_dl, num_epochs)
     18 
     19     # Repeat for each batch in the training set
---> 20     for i, data in enumerate(train_dl):
     21         # Get the input features and target labels, and put them on the GPU
     22         inputs, labels = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    631                 # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    632                 self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 633             data = self._next_data()
    634             self._num_yielded += 1
    635             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    675     def _next_data(self):
    676         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 677         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    678         if self._pin_memory:
    679             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data, self._pin_memory_device)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     52         else:
     53             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]
---> 54         return self.collate_fn(data)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py in default_collate(batch)
    263             >>> default_collate(batch)  # Handle `CustomType` automatically
    264     """
--> 265     return collate(batch, collate_fn_map=default_collate_fn_map)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py in collate(batch, collate_fn_map)
    140 
    141         if isinstance(elem, tuple):
--> 142             return [collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in transposed]  # Backwards compatibility.
    143         else:
    144             try:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py in (.0)
    140 
    141         if isinstance(elem, tuple):
--> 142             return [collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in transposed]  # Backwards compatibility.
    143         else:
    144             try:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py in collate(batch, collate_fn_map)
    117     if collate_fn_map is not None:
    118         if elem_type in collate_fn_map:
--> 119             return collate_fn_map[elem_type](batch, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map)
    120 
    121         for collate_type in collate_fn_map:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py in collate_numpy_array_fn(batch, collate_fn_map)
    167     # array of string classes and object
    168     if np_str_obj_array_pattern.search(elem.dtype.str) is not None:
--> 169         raise TypeError(default_collate_err_msg_format.format(elem.dtype))
    170 
    171     return collate([torch.as_tensor(b) for b in batch], collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map)

TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found object
```

Why does it throw the error and returns that it only found an object?

Comment: Inspect the individual elements within the numpy array. use the .dtype attribute of the arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering is because PyTorch's default collate function (`default_collate`) doesn't know how to handle the custom objects in your dataset.

The error message "TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found object" indicates that `default_collate` was expecting one of the listed types, but found a different type ("object") instead.

In your case, you have numpy arrays in your dataset, which the DataLoader tries to collate (combine) into a batch. PyTorch's DataLoader expects the data to be in the form of PyTorch tensors. Therefore, before sending the data to the DataLoader, you should convert your numpy arrays to PyTorch tensors.

Here's how you can resolve the issue:

1. Convert numpy arrays to PyTorch tensors in your dataset's `__getitem__` method.
2. Use these tensors when returning data from the `__getitem__` method.

Here's a modified version of what your dataset's `__getitem__` might look like:

```py
import torch

class YourDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, ...):  # your other initialization arguments
        ...

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        a, b = ...  # however you're getting your numpy arrays currently
        a_tensor = torch.from_numpy(a)
        b_tensor = torch.from_numpy(b)
        return a_tensor, b_tensor
```

By doing this, you're ensuring that whenever an item from the dataset is accessed, it's already in tensor form, which DataLoader can handle without any issues.

Comment: Thank you.
In addition to your suggestion I also had to change the dtype of the array to float64.
`np.array(self.df.iloc[idx, 2:51], dtype=np.float64)
latent_factors = torch.from_numpy(latent_factors)`